# How to authenticate users from two Yii apps on the same server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, yii

I've asked a similar question about this in the past concerning Single Sign On (SSO) but I realized that that only works for subdomains but in my case, I'm not using subdomains but just different Yii applications on the same server under one domain.

I have www.mydomain.com/app1 and www.mydomain.com/app2

Both applications use the same database and use the same tables for logging in.

**What I want to happen**:

*Accounts are the same for both applications*

1. User signs into app2 (or app1. It doesn't matter)
2. User is logged in and directed to home page.
3. User clicks the link from the menu that redirects them to app2 (or app1 if they came from app2)
4. User is redirected into app2 and skips login since they are signed in already and is redirected to the account's home page.
5. User clicks the logout link from the menu.
6. User is logged out from both applications.

**What is not happening**

(4). User is redirected to the app1 but is still prompted to sign in.

I then checked to see the cookies and session in app1 & app2 and I did the following for both main.php in the config folder:

```
// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'class'=>'WebUser',
    ),
    'session'=> array(
        'timeout'=> 1440
    ),
    'partyroles'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'class'=>'WebUser',
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

I've been stuck on this for the whole week and since the deadline is approaching soon, I think it's about time to get some needed help!

**EDIT** 
This is my configuration file main.php initiating sessions using CDbHttpSession. I'm now storing sessions into the database table called YiiSession:

```
    'sessionName'=>'app',
        'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',
        'autoCreateSessionTable'=> false,
        'connectionID'=>'db',
        'sessionTableName'=>'YiiSession',
        'useTransParentSessionID' =>($_POST['PHPSESSID']) ? true: false,
        'autoStart' => 'false',
        'cookieMode' => 'only',
        'timeout'=> 300
    ),
```

Logging in works now and sessions are being stored into the database but it's still not logging into both applications. Both applications have this identical configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first remark would be to check that the cookies had the good domain and thus that both apps received them and use the same session. It appears you already checked that and that that is okay.

Now, to determine which user is currently logged in, CWebUser looks for a [some prefix]__id variable in the session. That prefix can either be the `CWebUser->stateKeyPrefix` or, if empty, an MD5 based on the class name and the Yii application ID.

The Yii application ID in its turn is either specified by the `CApplication->id` property, or generated based on the base path of the application.

So the simplest way would be to add the same application ID to both your apps, it should then be able to use the same cookie voor both applications and will "detect the logged in user".

Just edit your configuration and add an "id" at the highest level for both your applications:

```
return array
(
    'id' => 'sharedApplicationId',

    'components' => array( ... ), 
);
```

This will result in `Yii::app()->id` returning the same ID, which will make `CWebUser::getStateKeyPrefix()` generate the same prefix and presto, both applications will find the __id variable in the session.

Alternatively, you can just configure the state key prefix for `CWebUser` via the configuration:

```
return array
(
    ...
    'components' => array
    (
       'user' => array
       (
          'stateKeyPrefix' => 'some_shared_prefix',
          ...
       ),
    ),
 );
```

This will only affect the CWebUser class then. It will then look for session variables like "some_shared_prefix__id" to determine the logged in user instead and not use the application ID. Either way should work.

So basically, even though you are sharing the database (and the sessions), if the prefix `CWebUser` ends up using differs because of a "bad" configuration, you'll just have `application1StateKeyPrefix__id` and `application2StateKeyPrefix__id` in the session and they won't see each others' logged in user.

Comment: I always read about placing it at the highest level. Is there any reason as to why? I'm curious about the configuration. It seems as if there is a hierarchy to the placement of your configuration but I want to know why! :)

Also, the 'id' can be anything, correct?

Comment: I also added that line of code you sent me to add to the top of my configuration and it wouldn't even run my application.

Comment: Well the configuration is set on the application object. So if you give it an "id" at the highest level that will be passed to Yii::app()->setId() and so on. Could you see if you can find what goes wrong and provide more info?

Comment: Logging in currently works. I updated by question. I'm using CdbHttpSessions now to store my sessions into the database but I'm still not successfully logging in both users into both applications. Any idea why? Shouldn't this work without using the application id since both applications are using the same db and table for YiiSession?