# Yii Framework 2.0 Automatically login in the subdomain

Tags: php, authentication, subdomain, yii2

I am working with Advanced Template of Yii framework 2.0. As we already know, There are the backend package and the frontend package separated from each other. I put the backend application in a subdomain and frontend in the main domain. Both packages use their own config file and share the same common/config/main.php file.

When I log in to the frontend, I am not automatically logged in to the backend which lives in the subdomain. How can I do to make user being logged in to the backend automatically after logging in to the frontend successfully?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693866/how-to-authenticate-users-from-two-yii-apps-on-the-same-server

Comment: @Masiorama: I just had a look at that article. Don't you think my case is a bit different since my issue is about main domain and sub domain. That article is about two application on the same one domain Or I just can use the same solution?

Comment: It's a similar scenario, but indeed it is different because you need to handle other problems, like the cross-domain sharing of cookies (not possibile) and so on. But it is the right approach. For instance, to solve the cross-domain problem you could decide to create an authentication centralized in a third application and that use that for the backend and frontend... tell me if you need me to elaborate more. :)

Comment: For instance, about the cookies problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies